# SET ROWCOUNT 1 performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, rowcount

I face an issue with SQL Server 2008 R2. If I execute the following statement, it takes less than 1 sec.

```
SELECT 
    A.REFERENCE_DATE AS REFERENCE_DATE
    ,A.MIS_BANK_ID AS BANK_ID
    ,'Unknown credit line' AS QUERY_LOG
    ,'STG_MIS_CREDIT_LINES_VALUE' AS [TABLE]
    ,'MIS_CREDIT_LINE_BRANCH_ID - MIS_CREDIT_LINE_ID' AS FIELD
    ,( 'MIS_CREDIT_LINE_BRANCH_ID: ' + A.MIS_CREDIT_LINE_BRANCH_ID + ' # MIS_CREDIT_LINE_ID: ' + A.MIS_CREDIT_LINE_ID ) AS [KEY]
    ,( A.MIS_CREDIT_LINE_BRANCH_ID + ' - ' + A.MIS_CREDIT_LINE_ID ) AS RESULT_1
    ,NULL AS RESULT_2
    ,NULL AS OUTSTANDING
FROM 
    STG_MIS_CREDIT_LINES_VALUE A
LEFT JOIN 
    STG_MIS_REG_CREDIT_LINES B ON A.REFERENCE_DATE = B.REFERENCE_DATE
                                  AND A.MIS_BANK_ID = B.MIS_BANK_ID
                                  AND A.MIS_CREDIT_LINE_BRANCH_ID = B.MIS_CREDIT_LINE_BRANCH_ID
                                  AND A.MIS_CREDIT_LINE_ID = B.MIS_CREDIT_LINE_ID
WHERE 
    B.MIS_CREDIT_LINE_ID IS NULL
    AND A.REFERENCE_DATE = '20131231'
```

While when I add a "SET ROWCOUNT 1" statement at the top, it takes more than 20 minutes to execute!

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1

SELECT 
    A.REFERENCE_DATE AS REFERENCE_DATE
    ,A.MIS_BANK_ID AS BANK_ID
    ,'Unknown credit line' AS QUERY_LOG
    ,'STG_MIS_CREDIT_LINES_VALUE' AS [TABLE]
    ,'MIS_CREDIT_LINE_BRANCH_ID - MIS_CREDIT_LINE_ID' AS FIELD
    ,( 'MIS_CREDIT_LINE_BRANCH_ID: ' + A.MIS_CREDIT_LINE_BRANCH_ID + ' # MIS_CREDIT_LINE_ID: ' + A.MIS_CREDIT_LINE_ID ) AS [KEY]
    ,( A.MIS_CREDIT_LINE_BRANCH_ID + ' - ' + A.MIS_CREDIT_LINE_ID ) AS RESULT_1
    ,NULL AS RESULT_2
    ,NULL AS OUTSTANDING
FROM 
    STG_MIS_CREDIT_LINES_VALUE A
LEFT JOIN 
    STG_MIS_REG_CREDIT_LINES B ON A.REFERENCE_DATE = B.REFERENCE_DATE
                                  AND A.MIS_BANK_ID = B.MIS_BANK_ID
                                  AND A.MIS_CREDIT_LINE_BRANCH_ID = B.MIS_CREDIT_LINE_BRANCH_ID
                                  AND A.MIS_CREDIT_LINE_ID = B.MIS_CREDIT_LINE_ID
WHERE 
    B.MIS_CREDIT_LINE_ID IS NULL
    AND A.REFERENCE_DATE = '20131231'
```

If I change the `ROWCOUNT` parameter to 2 or 0 or 100, or anything else, the query runs fast again (less than 1 sec).

**NOTICE 1:** The query actually returns 0 rows (and this is OK for me).

**NOTICE 2:** I cannot change the query adding a TOP 1 statement because mine is an ETL software and queries are "composed" by a fixed `SET ROWCOUNT 1` (which is hardcoded for technical reasons) and a free query written by corporate users; something like

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1

... SQL statement written by user ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Nicola

[EDIT]

**Execution plan (with ROWCOUNT 1)**
http://pastebin.com/RambD7Aj

**Execution plan (wiht ROWCOUNT 2)**
http://pastebin.com/cG4ngE4h

Comment: Sounds like your indexes aren't being hit when ROWCOUNT is 1.  Are you able to get the execution plan for both queries?

Comment: execution plans added

Comment: I noticed strange behaviour between SET ROWCOUNT 1 and SET ROWCOUNT 2.
The execution plan totally changes... :/

http://pastebin.com/RambD7Aj
http://pastebin.com/cG4ngE4h

Comment: The queryplans you have posted is the estimated plans. Do you think you could get a hold of the actual plans? It will show any discrepancies between estimated rowcount and actual rowcount. Your second query has gone parallel probably because the cost of the query ended up above the threshold for parallelism when you want two rows returned. That resulted in a plan this is faster and part of it is probably because it is parallel but the `rowcount 1` query should not be that much slower. There ought to be a faster plan in there somewhere for the case when 1 row returned is expected.

Comment: A related blog post [Inside the Optimizer: Row Goals In Depth](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/18/inside-the-optimiser-row-goals-in-depth.aspx).

Comment: Hi Mikael, please see my reply to Vladimir.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for sure without looking at execution plans, but it sounds like the when you first add `SET ROWCOUNT 1` it tries to create new execution plan that does not uses indexes, when you rerun it again it uses correct execution plan.

Here are couple things to try.

- add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the of your query.
- Try replacing `SET ROWCOUNT 1` with `SELECT TOP 1`
- look at execution plans for both queries.
- Add `ROW_NUMBER()` and turn your query into derived table with where clause where rn = 1

Comment: execution plans added, hope it helps

Comment: I noticed strange behaviour between SET ROWCOUNT 1 and SET ROWCOUNT 2.
The execution plan totally changes... :/

http://pastebin.com/RambD7Aj
http://pastebin.com/cG4ngE4h

Comment: can you add execution plan without the `SET ROWCOUNT` statement.

Comment: based on the fact that one plan is using hash join, it hints on missing index or plan not picking correct index. Also try adding `OPTION MAXDOP(1)` to force single threading and than try adding `OPTION ( RECOMPILE, QUERYTRACEON 8649 )` which forces multi-threading

Comment: Here all execution plans:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7161916/SQL/Execution_Plans.zip

I tried to add a TOP 10000 to the SELECT statement and then also leave the SET ROWCOUNT 1 (see "TOP 10000.subplan" file).

The behaviour is very similar to all other cases. The only "outsider" is the SET ROWCOUNT 1 (see "1.subplan").

It drives me crazy... :(

Comment: Give this a try, when you run `SET ROWCOUNT 1` at the end of the query add this `OPTION ( RECOMPILE, QUERYTRACEON 8649 )` let me know what happens

Comment: Hi Vladimir, here you can find the execution plan: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7161916/SQL/QUERYTRACEON.sqlplan

It takes about 5 minutes (less than over 20 minutes, but higher than 1 sec).

NOTE: I changed the reference date to 20140131 because users loaded new data inside tables and 20131231 is no longer present.